# Could Java EE Batch Job wait event?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, batch-processing

I should implement business flow with many async calls to external system: I send async SOAP and don't wait it (I only get ack), response (SOAP message on my endpoint) can be send back in hours and than I continue my flow. Could java ee batch (JSR 352) do this? Or I should to look up something else?

**UPDATE:**
One is possible simple solution is that one step would read data from blocking queue, but I don't like this solution. I could lock my flow if count of waiting step would be more than available threads

**UDPATE2:**

```
<job id="myJob" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.0">
    <step id="myStep" next="myStep2" >
        <batchlet ref=".MyBatchlet"/>
        <stop on="COMPLETED" />
    </step>
    <step id="myStep2" >
        <batchlet ref="MyBatchlet2"/>
    </step>
</job>
```

I could continue by this code:

```
long jid = jo.start("myJob", new Properties());
long jid2 = jo.restart(jid, new Properties());
```

MyBatchlet2 never starts

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no out of the box way to implement what you want, but maybe you can implement a workaround [using the stop() and restart() methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/operations/JobOperator.html#restart-long-java.util.Properties-).

Comment: can you handle the response event and began a subflow with a new different job ?, this will allow you to continue with your batching approach

Comment: I need to fetch data from previous steps

Comment: What do you need to do with you response ?, because if you make an async call your job does not wait and continues executing?

Comment: Look, I make soap request get ack and wait soap request on the other endpoint to continue my job

Comment: If you are doing the async call using a future object, you can pass this object between steps an on the correct on, check if the response is already available.

Comment: Yes, i misunderstood sorry.

Comment: Any way how to continue execution from specific step?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html, on this link you can found an example of restart but not a step restart for this you need to create a checkpoint the restar the job, and it will began after the checkpoint i think